# Spring-boot RestAPI post org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

My github code https://github.com/prabhatpankaj/SpringREST_API/

[image]

output

```
output { "timestamp": 1498443503678, "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request", "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableEx‌​ception", "message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of com.exaple.objects.User out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.exaple.objects.User out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1546ea93; line: 1, column: 1]", "path": "/api/user/" }
```

Comment: output

{ "timestamp": 1498443503678, "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request", "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException", "message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of com.exaple.objects.User out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.exaple.objects.User out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1546ea93; line: 1, column: 1]", "path": "/api/user/" }

Comment: get request is file ... But I am getting this error in post

Comment: avoid images. Post code and exception. It seems a json problem

Comment: @Prabhat post your json request body object

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you send array of users JSON rather than one user.

Remove the `[` and `]` from JSON you send and try once more